# UIImagePickerController crashing in Xcode 7 beta

Tags: uiimagepickercontroller, xcode7, ios9

I'm running an older app built with Xcode 6 and `iOS8`, in the new Xcode 7 beta.
The `UIImagePickerController` seems to be crashing when I click on the "Moments" album in simulator. 
I have changed the deployment target to be `iOS9` and that's the only change I have made.

The picker controller opens fine and shows the available albums but when I click on the album, the app crashes with the following error.

```
2015-06-18 22:22:15.052 Asset Ops[7863:329073] UIAlertController Render start : 2015-06-18T22:22:15.052+0530

2015-06-18 22:22:15.089 Asset Ops[7863:329073] UIAlertController Render end : 2015-06-18T22:22:15.090+0530

2015-06-18 22:22:16.424 Asset Ops[7863:329073] PUUIAlbumListViewController Render start : 2015-06-18T22:22:16.424+0530

2015-06-18 22:22:16.426 Asset Ops[7863:329073] UIImagePickerController Render start : 2015-06-18T22:22:16.427+0530

2015-06-18 22:22:16.953 Asset Ops[7863:329073] UIImagePickerController Render end : 2015-06-18T22:22:16.954+0530

2015-06-18 22:22:16.954 Asset Ops[7863:329073] PUUIAlbumListViewController Render end : 2015-06-18T22:22:16.954+0530

Exception: EXC_ARITHMETIC (code=EXC_I386_DIV, subcode=0x0))
```

Any clues why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded the new Xcode 7 Beta 2. 
This is now fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed in Xcode 7 beta 2. Download latest prerelease version of Xcode 7 Beta.